# Is it possible to create a GNU+Linux Tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I tried to apply a GNU+Linux Tag to a question, but the system automatically breaks the Tag into either GNU or Linux.

Without the possibility of applying a GNU+Linux Tab, might people stray from using the freedom committed, full form when adding Tags? The current automated solution has its own elegance, though.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it in the following way:  [gnu-linux](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnu-linux).

As spaces are taken as delimiters for tag creation, `gnu linux` would be parsed as two different tags.

So, include a hyphen between the words, and you'll be all good!

Answer (score 1):

While I agree the correct tag would be [gnu-linux](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnu-linux) it's for most users simpler to tag questions with simply [linux](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux).

I created a tag synonym from [gnu-linux](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnu-linux) to [linux](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linux).